# How to initialize a struct/class that has huge array members?

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list, object-initializers

Is there a way to initialize a C++ `struct`/`class` with very large array members? I would like to initialize them by filling them with any kind of data besides an empty array. The following code is defined in a dependency of mine:

```
#define WORSE_DATA_LENGTH 8000

struct LibraryStruct {
    int lots;
    int of;
    int fields;
    int huge_array[2000]; // how to initialize this?
    char even_worse[WORSE_DATA_LENGTH]; // how to initialize this?
};
```

Note that there are not any defined constructors. It should be assumed that I cannot edit this `struct`.

Here's the code I've tried to make use of `LibraryStruct` with:

```
int main() {
    // I can do this, but can I fill these arrays with data?
    // Say, for example:
    //  - fill huge_array with 2000 random ints 
    //  - fill even_worse with the current day of the week in 20 different languages
    const auto my_struct = LibraryStruct{5, 8, 900, {}, {}};
    return 0;
}
```

I've looked around and all of the examples with initializer lists with arrays that I've found have arrays with a small number of elements, and I think this example demonstrates a need for another way to initialize arrays.

Comment: `int huge_array[2000] = {};`? Initialize with what?

Comment: You could consider `std::vector` instead if you are worried about a potential stack overflow.

Comment: `std::array<int, WORSE_DATA_LENGTH> my_array = my_array_builder();`?

Comment: Initialize an array with 2000 different values?

Comment: @ChrisMM @Mitu Just fill with any values really, what I actually need to do is accept a `LibraryStruct` as a function parameter, and return a new `LibraryStruct` with a few fields changed, so `huge_array` would actually be a copy of the  array field within the `LibraryStruct` given to me. I've tried to distill it down to the more fundamental issue I'm having.

Comment: @karobar So you want a copy constructor?

Comment: @John I don't think so, because a few of the fields should be different

Comment: Performance doesn't really depend on *how* you initialise. It depends on *whether* you initialise. If you don't need it, don"t do it. Assign individual fields. Otherwise, pick the way you think is most readable.